# Create an array of SKShapeNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to Swift development and I'm trying to create a simple racing game.  The road in the game has lane markers that animate from the top of the screen to the bottom then loop back up to the top.  I am using SKShapeNodes for the lane line markers.

I have been able to get one lane marker to work and now I just need to create an array(I think?) of lane markers so that I can have 2 columns of lanes and enough to give the game the illusion of being a real road.

I'm able to create the array but I get a run-time error when I try to add a SKShapeNode to it.  The error I get is:

Thread 1: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)`

```
fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer
```

Here is the relevant source code:

```
class PlayScene: SKScene {
    let road = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "road8")
    let car = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "car")

    let laneLineNode = SKShapeNode()
    var laneLineNodeArray = [[SKShapeNode]]()
    var groundSpeed = 25
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //draw a lane line
        var path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        var laneLineWidth = self.size.width / 85
        var laneLineHeight = self.size.height / 11
        var laneLine = CGRect(x: ((self.frame.size.width / 5) * 2), y:            
           (self.frame.size.height + laneLineHeight), 
           width: laneLineWidth, height: laneLineHeight)

        laneLineNode.lineWidth = 0
        laneLineNode.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(laneLine, nil)
        laneLineNode.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
        laneLineNode.zPosition = 2

        //THIS IS THE LINE I GET THE ERROR ON
        laneLineNodeArray[0][0] = laneLineNode

        self.addChild(self.road)
        self.addChild(self.laneLineNode)
        self.addChild(self.car)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {        
        //move the lane lines
        scrollLaneLines(self.scene!)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all... You are closing your class too soon with this code:

```
  var groundSpeed = 25
} // <--
```

Second... Your are not initializing your array before using it. In my test, I got the error because of that.

You should use this syntax to initialize your Array or use append as @Arnab suggest.

```
let laneLineNode = SKShapeNode()
var laneLineNodeArray = [[laneLineNode]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created an empty array so far. Use "append" to add data to the array before you access the elements by index.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!  I was able to get it to work with this in Class PlayScene:

```
var laneLineNodeArray:[[SKShapeNode]] = []
```

and this in func didMoveToView:

```
    //draw a lane line
    var path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    var laneLineWidth = self.size.width / 85
    var laneLineHeight = self.size.height / 11
    var laneLine = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.frame.size.height + laneLineHeight),
        width: laneLineWidth, height: laneLineHeight)

    var laneLineRowNumber: Int
    var laneLineY: CGFloat
    for r in 0...6 {
        var laneLineRow:[LaneLine] = []
        laneLineRowNumber = r
        for c in 0...1 {
            let laneLineNode = LaneLine()
            laneLineNode.lineWidth = 0
            laneLineNode.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(laneLine, nil)
            laneLineNode.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
            laneLineNode.zPosition = 2
            //lanelineY determines the Y placement of the lane.
            laneLineY = self.frame.size.height - (CGFloat((laneLineHeight) * 2)
                * CGFloat(r))

            if c == 0 {
                laneLineNode.position = CGPointMake(laneWidth * 2, laneLineY)
            }
            else if c == 1 {
                laneLineNode.position = CGPointMake(laneWidth * 3, laneLineY)
            }
            self.addChild(laneLineNode)
            laneLineRow.append(laneLineNode)
        }
    laneLineNodeArray.append(laneLineRow)
    }
```